# Hiding two Relative Layout and ListView

Tags: android, list, android-listview

I have two button One For New Game And another one for Old Game And I have two relative layout respectively. I want to toggle in same activity between these two buttons when i click NewGame Button then First NewGame ListView(inSide Relative Layout) Should be visible and another should be invisible ViceVersa.

```
            case R.id.btn_old_game:
            mBtnOldGame.setEnabled(false);
            play_new_game.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            historyRaltiveLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                             loadHistoryGameList();
                          break;
        case R.id.btn_play_game:
            mBtnOldGame.setEnabled(true);
            getListView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            historyRaltiveLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            play_new_game.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            loadGamesItemsList();
            break;
```

So the problem in this is , when i click on old game Button it is working but if I again click to New Game Button it is not working and it remains to OldGame ListView(OldGame Relative Layout).

Comment: problem not defined yet.

Comment: is `switch` case for `R.id.btn_play_game` working? use `Log.d()` to debug it.